# About PHP+Apache Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

The current site is the the dynamic php as a.php.

I want user visite my site can use a.html,and not through original a.php.
In apache2.x, set apache's httpd.conf inside:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   <Directory "c:/www/xxx">
     rewriteengine on
     rewritebase /
     RewriteRule ^a.html$ a.php
   </ Directory>
```

Above is the most simple example. Html directly parsed into php.
Now,The question is: a.php and a.html can be accessed.but user visite the default page always is a.php.

I want to know the above setting is wrong? Or addition to my in apache configuration must also be in the foreground of the original file in the corresponding dynamic URLs turned into static? If the  we wanted to change ? In order to achieve the purpose of the "hidden a.php"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need in your .htaccess to handle this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.html [R=301,L]

# internal forward from abc.html to abc.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write redirect rules in htaccess file instead, and place it on the root.

Here is an example what could be done (put this in .htaccess file and place on root):

```
RewriteEngine On

#/ rewrite html to php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php?redirectLoopStopper=1 [QSA,L]

#/ redirect .php to .html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(redirectLoopStopper=1)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ PATH/TO/PROJECT/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.
But it have some error:ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: ok. Actually I wrote this to give you some idea on how to do it. You have to alter this code a bit more to get what you want (it will be very near to this one). but remember, use htaccess file..

Comment: I have a new question:
Mouse over the url above.Is still display the original url(*.php).However jump is normal(*.html). Can you solve this problem?

Comment: url is abc.php,it can redirect to abc.html
but in IE status bar,it show abc.php (why isn't abc.html)?